# Merge objects inside arrays, which are inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

currently I have a little problem, which I am not quite able to solve. I have an array, which can contain single, or more arrays, which than can contain multiple objects. So for instance:

```
const arr = [
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ]
]
```

And I want to merge the objects based on a specific property (here "value") into an array, so that my result will look like that:

```
const result = ["value A", "value B", "value C", "value A", "value B", "value C"]
```

Someone got an idea for that? Thank you!

Comment: Can you confirm your expected output, please? You wrote `const result = {"value A", "value B", "value C", "value A", "value B", "value C"}` (which is not valid JS) altought I assume you meant `const result = ["value A", "value B", "value C", "value A", "value B", "value C"]`

Comment: Your result is not possible as you depict an object with only values and no keys. Did you mean to use an array?

Comment: Ooopsie, yeah, my result should be an array of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = [
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ]
]

let x = arr.flat().map(v=>v.value);

console.log(x);
```

Comment: Dude, thats awesome! Works like a charm. I have to look into, what flat actually does. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your desired result is an array, and not object.
The output example of yours is invalid.

Anyway, use simple reduce:

```js
const arr = [
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ]
]

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const values = cur.map(({value}) => value);
  return acc.concat(values)
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const arr = [
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "value": "value A"
    },
    {
      "value": "value B"
    },
    {
      "value": "value C"
    }
  ]
]

function mergeArray( arr, property ) {
  const res = [];
  for (const innerArr of arr) {
    for (const obj of innerArr) {
      res.push(obj[property]);
    }
  }
  return res;
}

console.log(mergeArray(arr, "value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use nested reduce and map methods of the Array.prototype

```js
{
  const arr = [
    [{
        "value": "value A"
      },
      {
        "value": "value B"
      },
      {
        "value": "value C"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "value": "value A"
      },
      {
        "value": "value B"
      },
      {
        "value": "value C"
      }
    ]
  ];
  
  const newArr = arr.reduce((carry, item) => {
     carry.push(...item.map(item2 => item2.value))
     return carry;
  }, [])
  
  console.log(newArr)
}
```